# Could not find an overload for '*' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: ios, swift

Started learning Swift earlier this week and I'm doing some quick practices to learn it.

I'm trying to convert Celcius into Farenheit, this is what I have:

```
    var tempInCelcius = 30

    var tempInFarenheit = tempInCelcius * 1.8 + 32
```

However I get the below error:

```
error: could not find an overload for '*' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

Am I missing something really obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tempInCelcius` is declared as `Int` (the default type for integer literals).
 `1.8` is inferred as `Double`.

In Swift you cannot do math with different types.

Solution is to declare `tempInCelcius` explicitly

```
var tempInCelcius : Double = 30
```

or implicitly

```
var tempInCelcius = 30.0
```

as `Double`. Then the multiplication works.

```
var tempInFahrenheit = tempInCelcius * 1.8 + 32
```

Unlike variables literal numbers like `32` have to distinct type and are inferred to the proper type of the operation (if possible)